# Cannot find Prism.PrismApplication

Tags: prism

I just started my first WPF app using MVVMLight, PRISM, and DryIoc.  The App.xaml refers to prism:PrismApplication as described in https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/getting-started.html without error.

```
<prism:PrismApplication x:Class="DYC.MembershipAndDues.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DYC.MembershipAndDues"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DYC.MembershipAndDues.ViewModel"
    xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d1p1:Ignorable="d"
    DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

In the App.xaml.cs, Prism.PrismApplication cannot be found.  I found PrismApplicationBase in the object explorer, which works for App.xaml.cs, but in App.xaml, prism:PrismApplicationBase cannot be found.  There appears to be a disconnect between the xaml declaration at xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" and the packages that I have loaded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="DryIoc.dll" version="4.0.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MvvmLight" version="5.4.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MvvmLightLibs" version="5.4.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Prism.Core" version="7.2.0.1422" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Prism.DryIoc" version="7.2.0.1422" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Prism.Wpf" version="7.2.0.1422" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Found it!  It's included in the dependancy injector container, i.e. Prism.DryIoc or Prism.Unity depending on which container you are using.